# Нужна помощь в mysql и html (не получается отправить данные в базу данных)

Tags: php, html, база-данных, post

помогите пожалуйста , весь php файл не хочет работать.
Код из index.html:

```
<form action="rezultat.php" method="post">
    <h3>Имя:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <h3>Дата:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="date">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Код из rezultat.php:

```
<?php
    
    // Переменные с формы
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $text = $_POST['date'];
    $prize= $_POST['prize'];
    
    // Параметры для подключения
    $db_host = "XXXX"; //хост
    $db_user = "XXXX"; // Логин БД
    $db_password = "XXXX"; // Пароль БД
    $db_base = 'XXXX'; // Имя БД
    $db_table = "XXXX"; // Имя Таблицы БД
    
    // Подключение к базе данных
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);

    // Если есть ошибка соединения, выводим её и убиваем подключение
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Ошибка : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    
    $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (name,date,prize) VALUES ('$name','$text','$prize')");
    
    if ($result == true){
        echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
    }else{
        echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
    }

?>
```

Открывок кода с prize:

```
 <script> 
   var canvas, ctx,ctxW = 600,ctxH = 600,wheel,prize;
```

Comment: не выполняется проверка isset($_POST['prize']). этого параметра нет в данных. поэтому условие не отрабатывает

Comment: Var prize он у меня идет с рулетки , которая на канвасе саписана . Он создан и не удаляется в теории . я оставил просто имя и дату , то есть данные с формы и у меня все равно пишет что данные не загружены в бд

Comment: Логи ошибок смотрели?

Comment: В логах по этому вопросу пусто. последняя запись ошибки это моя проверка пароля , ввел специально неправильный и он вывел ошибку подключения.

Comment: а хотя вот что нашел. Warning:  mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/rezultat.php

Comment: Добавьте еще дамп базы (без данных). Какая версия php и Mysql используются?

Comment: дамп базы сделал , от формы идет значение null . Версия MariaDB 10.2.33

Answer (score 2):

Вы думаете, что если в комментарии написали красиво: Убиваем подключение, то всё должно работать, Вам видимо доплачивают за лишние строки комментариев и пустые строки.

Включаем Вангу: в обработчике ожидается 3 параметра, форма отправляет только 2, а в БД скорее всего на столбце prize стоит NOT NULL - это так навскидку.

И почему нет варнинга в обработчике, что $prize не определена, вывод ошибок включён?

И зачем в html-форме инпутам задавать значение type="text", если они по дефолту text?

И зачем кнопку делать инпутом с type="submit", если для кнопки есть тег button, который по дефолту submit и для js тег form - это событие submit?

Comment: коментарии я пишу для себя , ведь когда у тебя 7 отдельных фреймов не сразу можно понять где какой элемент страницы. вывод ошибок включен, но он не выводит почти ничего, ведь только через логи заметил что даже форма отправляет не 2 ( когда я оставил имя и время ) переменные , а 1 и бывает и 0.  От того что я поставлю type ничего существенного  не изменится . в бд на всех элементах стоит возможность null.

Comment: Не нужен комментарий для функции die )))

Comment: @ernest0 обработчик ошибок нужен ГЛОБАЛЬНЫЙ, пишется за 10 минут: админу логи, пользуну - разукрашка 404-500, и вообще что Вы тут назвали фреймом? ))) Сравнение на булев true тождественно должно быть, а не приведением, зачем тогда оно можно просто if($result) сделать, и так далее.... (конкатенация в двойных кавычках) ...

Comment: @ernest0 начни с html короче ;)

Comment: @ernest0 если сильно надо третий параметр писать в БД, который не передаётся формой и в БД разрешено хранить null, то проверь $prize= $_POST['prize'] ?? nul; Если пых у тебя естественно 7+

Comment: окей , сенк ю )

Comment: а на счет фреймов я же не скинул абсолютно весь код страницы , соотвественно вы не можете говорить где у меня есть фреймы а где нет :C

Comment: @ernest0, какие к чёрту фреймы, ты жесть какую-то написал ДАЖЕ НА ПРОЦЕДУРКЕ ))) ладно, если ты в начале пути, то так оно и должно быть, не бросай: каждый день читай по одной функции из доков по PHP, через 3 месяца прозреешь ;) главное не бросай и тебе тут третий параметр не нужен в запросе, если разрешено хранить null, то убери $prize= $_POST['prize'];

Answer (score 1):

Ммммм, вы в sql запросе кавычки не поставили

```php
$db_table = "`XXXX`";
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (`name`,`date`,`prize`)
                          VALUES ('$name','$text','$prize')");
```

Comment: спасибо , исправлю